# Hyperlink a powerpoint slide

Tags: beamer, powerpoint

Is it possible to hyperlink an animated powerpoint slide to beamer ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can include a link which will open the powerpoint file with your default program for this file type. Your desired slide should be the first one in the file, otherwise you will have to scroll to it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\href{run:/absolut/path/to/file/test.ppt}{link to ppt}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```